# Сложная архитектура приложения - это норма или косяк программиста?

Tags: архитектура

Я новичок и даже не знаю как называется эта тема и как ее гуглить. Проблема думаю касается любого языка.

Вот пишу я приложения и в какой то момент, добавляя очередную функцию, я вдруг осознаю, что для её добавления мне приходится делать очень много правок в других частях приложения и даже иногда править смежные функции.

Порой это доходит до того, что возникают сложность с добавлением какой либо возможности в приложении.

Небольшой пример в виде псевдокода. Возьмем например React:

```
<MainComponent>
  <Products>
    {products.map(item=> return <ProductCard />)}
  </Products>
  <ButtonGetMoreProducts />
</MainComponent>
```

В подобном примере кода, каждый компонент `<ProductCard />` может содержать какие то колбэки которые меняют состояние родителя/смежных компонентов которые в свою очередь меняют что то еще и всю эту цепочку приходится учитывать при дальнейшей поддержке кода.

Особенно сложно если компоненты получают какие то реляционные данные с сервера которые влияют друг на друга. Я пытаюсь соблюдать атомарность компонентов, но это не помогает.

Вопрос: нормально ли вышеописанное и если нет то как с этим бороться? Что почитать/посмотреть? И как общим словом "обзывается" данная проблема? Как её решаете вы?

Comment: Это наверное куда-то в сторону https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling

Comment: Еще посмотрите в сторону DRY и SRP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> нормально ли это

все кто вырастают эдак в мидла сталкиваются с этим, та что да, нормально. но вот хорошо ли это, конечно нет.

> атомарность не помогает

она расчитана лишь на поддержание вменяемой иерархии тегов и их идентификаторов\классов в проекте, но не более того, потому и не помогает

> как это называется

такой цельный проект в котором его компоненты мешают друг друг называется "монолитом"

> как бороться

решения в зависимости от стэка и масштаба называются по разному:

сами комппоненты в целом проекте:

- в вебе - микросервисы
- в геймдэве - акторы
- в дэвопс - контейнеры

связующее звено для компонентов:

- sql
- rest api

инструменты во многих яп предназначеные для этого:

- нэймспейсы
- инкапсуляция

> как это решаете вы

эм... прям как в анекдоте:

- как вы решили эту проблему?
- мы решили что это не проблема 8-)

// ну а если серьёзно, я этим сейчас просто не занимаюсь